# Override def when extending Trait with same val

Tags: scala, inheritance, types

I know this syntax won't compile but I was wondering if something like this is possible ... to be able to override something defined in a trait in an inheriting case class with a val of equal name.

```
trait A {
    def id: Int

    def getId: Int = id
}

case class Foo(id: Int, graphId: Int) extends A {
    override def id: Int = graphId
}

val f = Foo(1,2)

f.id // => 1
f.getId // => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it: why are you declaring `id` twice???

Either `case class Foo(id: Int) extends A` or `case class Foo(graphId: Int) extends A { def id = graphId }` will work.

Comment: Because `id` in the object `Foo` represents something different than what the `id` in trait `A` represents. Think of it like this: trait `A` represents @Dima some operations over a graph of entities. `Foo.id` however is the `id` of a `Foo` in a relational database, which is different than its `graphId`. I would like `Foo` to have all the capabilities of `A`, using the correct id (its `graphId`) and also be able to contain its relational database `id` and have that "id" be names exactly `id`.

Comment: If it represents something  different, it should be called something different. 
If you have two different fields called `id`, _which one_ do you expect to get when you do `foo.id`, and _how_ would you possibly access the other one?

Comment: I understand practically why what I am asking wouldn't make sense. But that is not true theoretically. It would be possible to have the operations in `trait A` scoped to the `id` that has been set via an inheriting class. And still have the inheriting class have another version of that same definition. What I'm looking for is something like `private / scoped only to this trait def id`. I don't care about accessing the `def id` in `trait A` ever. I just want to use it to perform various operations over it.

Comment: Accessing it is different than having it be used by an internal function (consider private variables). I don't care about calling `f.id` and ever getting `2`. BUT, when I defined `f` it is theoretically possible for some value to be defined at a different memory address than where `Foo`'s `id` is stored, and whenever a function from the scope of `trait A` is called it references that address's value.

Comment: Call it `_id` then?

Comment: While this is certainly a viable alternative it does not exactly help or answer the question. I already have a lot of code that inherits `trait A` (where `id = id`). Changing `A` to now have an `_id` would mean I would need to change all those other inheritances to implement `_id`.

Comment: Then rename `id` in `Foo` to `dbId` or something ... You can't possibly have "a lot of code" like that, because it wouldn't compile :)

Comment: By "have a lot of code like that" I mean I have 25 `case class Bar(id: String) extends A` where it is correct that `Bar.id` is the `id` that I want to operate over the functions in `trait A`. I am now adding a single new class where that is not the case and I did not want to have to go back and refactor those classes nor call my val in `Foo` something other than `id`. If it's not possible that's ok, I just figured that theoretically it is possible and was wondering if Scala supported it in some way.

Comment: "Go back and refactor" is a single button click in an IDE. But if you don't want to do that, just add `def dbId = id` to the trait. And override that in foo.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is actually almost right.

If you try and compile it the compiler will hint to the actual problem:

```
error: value id is defined twice
  conflicting symbols both originated in file '<console>'
       override def id: Int = graphId
```

So the actual problem is that case classes will automatically generate getter methods for all constructor arguments.

You can get your code to compile by using:

```
trait A {

    def id: Int

    def getId: Int = id
}

case class Foo(id: Int, graphId: Int) extends A {
   override def getId: Int = graphId
}


val f = Foo(1,2)

f.id // => 1
f.getId // => 2
```

Comment: So that is almost true (well, it's true in that it compiles and works). But if you look at the last line: `f.getId // => 2` will not happen. `f.getId` will return `1` because you have set `id` in `trait A` equal to `id` in `Foo`. But I would like the `id` being used in the functions of `trait A` to be `graphId`. Let's say `trait A` is actually called `trait GraphOperations` and `Foo` can have a node in a graph with the id `graphId`. However, it also has a separate `id` pointing to its row in a relational database. I would like the graph operations on `Foo` to operate over the correct `graphId`

Comment: I didn't noticed that requirement. I updated the answer. Basically you just need to override the getId method and make it return what you need.

Comment: Ah yes this is true but unfortunately `getId` is just a simple example. I have 50 or so functions in my trait, all of which use `id`, and I would not like to override all of them, hence this question. There are many ways I could get around my issue but they all would require refactors. I'm looking for a syntactic way of doing this specific trick (that I understand may or may not be possible).

Comment: I don't get what you are aiming to. If you want in someway to have that id is resolved differently when used from the "outside" w.r.t. when it is used from inside the trait I don't think you can achieve that without a major refactor of the code (i.e. having both `id` and `idInner` which defaults to `id` but that can be overridden independently from `id` and having all other methods refer to `idInner`). However without further clarification these are all conjectures...